# как получить login в процедуре?

Tags: postgresql

Использую PostgreSQL 15. Авторизация на сервере под своим логином у каждого пользователя.

Использую процедуру для установки галочки в таблице.

Сотрудник должен иметь право ставить галочку (bool) в таблице, но снять ее уже право не имеет.

Контроль может снимать и ставить галочку.

Как в procedure узнать под каким логином или ролью запущена процедура?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что такое "login" в данном контексте?

Comment: Acinit
 на сервере postgres есть роли и логины, сотрудники авторизуются под своими логинами.

Comment: попробуйте сделать запрос в `pg_user`, оттуда можно и достать роль

Comment: измените процедуру таким образом, проверяя `pg_user` на значение `usename`